# Updating database column with checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
echo "<form action=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\" method=\"POST\">";
    if ($isAdmin === '1'){
        echo "<input id=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox\" type=\"checkbox\" checked=\"checked\" value=\"1\" />";
    } else {
        echo "<input id=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"0\" />";
    }
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"formSubmit\" value=\"X\" />";
echo "</form>";
```

The above code is inside a while loop so it makes a form for each user. My php code looks like this:

```
$status = '0';
if (isset($_POST['checkbox']) && $_POST['checkbox'] == '1') {
    $status = $_POST['checkbox'];
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE members SET isAdmin = ? WHERE id = \"$id\"");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $status);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

Without actually submitting the form to the server, why does the admin user become a non-admin user just by refreshing the page?

---

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<?php echo ($checked)? '1' : '0'; ?>"<?php if($checked) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?> />
    <input type="hidden" id="userid" name="userid" value="<? echo $members_row['id']; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value=">>" />
</form>

<?

$status = '0';
if (isset($_POST['checkbox']) && $_POST['checkbox'] == '1') {
    $status = $_POST['checkbox'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE members SET isAdmin = ? WHERE id = \"$id\"");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $status);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

Comment: A little more code please. How does `$isAdmin` get set?

Comment: Sorry, it is pulled from the initially set by the db as 0 or non-admin user. The form in question is how an admin user would grant non-admin users access.

Comment: Seems to me you should be putting the close bracket at the end of that php snippet so all that code executes on `$_POST['checkbox']`. You execute every time you reload at `$status = '0'`, do you not?

Comment: @Rasclatt so that fixes one issue, I just tested and it doesn't actually update the db.

Comment: why use prepared statements and bind only one of the parameters and then directly embed the one parameter that is obvious - `id`?

Comment: @BradonKelley Simply refreshing your page will not up update your database using your updated code *(my answer)* because you need the post for it to trigger the update. You will have some other issue going on somewhere on your page that is doing it.

Comment: Your input, by the way, doesn't have a `name` attribute. Put `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the page, that should draw a warning since there is no `$_POST['id']`

Comment: Are you still seeing it update on refresh or what is the current issue?

Comment: it doesn't do anything to the database, still have the same issue

Comment: Do you have more code you can show? What's there should work as intended.

Comment: Actually you are calling `$_POST['id']` when in your form you have it named `userid`

Answer (score 0):

Couple things, move your bracket to the end of the php snippet, and just check that the post is set but not that it equals anything. `$status` will be used to update it at the time of post. Side note, since the form is in a loop, `id="checkbox"` is going to be a problem when/if you use javascript. `id="*"` should to be unique in order to provide value. Finally, the origin of `$id` is unknown from the script provided, you will want to make sure you `bind_param` on that value as well (perhaps it should be provided by the post?). Not sure on the origin of that variable so hard to comment on that.

```
$checked = ($isAdmin == '1');
?>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
    <input id="checkbox" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo ($checked)? '1' : '0'; ?>"<?php if($checked) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?> />
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="X" />
</form>
<?php //continue with loop
```

Presumably this is at the top since your forms reference `PHP_SELF`:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    $status = $_POST['checkbox'];
    // The $id variable is suspect here. Probably should be provided by the post?
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE members SET isAdmin = ? WHERE id = '$id'");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $status);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

If I were doing this, I would either use a function or a class/method to make it more human-readable and reusable:

```
function updateUserRole($id,$status,$mysqli)
    {
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE members SET isAdmin = ? WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('si', $status,$id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }

// To execute, include the function
// then run the "if" condition
if (isset($_POST['checkbox']))
    updateUserRole($_POST['id'],$_POST['checkbox'],$mysqli);
```

Comment: That php code doesn't fixes the issue just recreates the original  issue

Comment: Where are you getting `$id` from? You have hardcoded the `$id` so it will always update that id value with the admin post value from the form.

Comment: You probably need to provide an `id` value in your form so you post the id with the admin value at time of submission. No? Something like: `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />`

Comment: Then in the processing, you do `$id = $_POST['id'];` Then you also bind that when you run the sql.

Comment: The $id actually is coming from the db from another query statement

Comment: You say in your post *"...form for each user..."* but your form doesn't carry any identifier of the user's `id` so how will the post know who is who when you submit the form?

Comment: yea noticed that duh, I'm dumb! working on creating my hidden field.